# Xamarin iOS : Error MT2101 Can't resolve the reference 'Foundation.NSString Foundation.NSBundle::GetLocalizedString

Tags: xamarin, build-error

I am building a **xamarin ios** project which fails with the following error
I have tried clean and rebuild several times

```
  Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 
    'Foundation.NSString Foundation.NSBundle::GetLocalizedString(System.String,System.String,System.String)', referenced from the method 
    'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WkWebViewRenderer/CustomWebViewUIDelegate::.cctor()'
 in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. (MT2101)
```

Comment: Hi, have a check with `WkWebViewRenderer` in your project whether it contains some error conver about String between NSString.

Comment: I am trying to load a Xamarin Forms Content page in my ios project. The error arises once i add the xamarin forms reference

Comment: Okey, could you share the code about that? It will be helpful to check the problem.

Comment: i am trying to follow the guide of this project https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

Comment: From shared link, whehter your project is a [NativeForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms)?

Comment: @JuniorJiang No my project is Xamarin.ios